is variable grind-size better for richer pour-over coffee brews?
I am not very knowledgeable about coffee equipment so this question arises.

I am aware that almost all advice on coffee grinders is to seek small variation of coffee grind size, and especially eliminating "fines".

However I am also aware that some fines, or at least more variation in coffee grind size, gives richer, fuller-body, pour-over brews.


So does this mean my current Hario Skerton will give me richer, fuller-body pour-over brews than the Kingrinder K6 that several have recommended should be my next investment?
To be clear, I am not seeking a tea-like pure clarity.
I am seeking an espresso-like americano-like coffee, with body, aroma, texture. (I can't afford an espresso machine yet hence the pour-over)

You have several questions about achieving a certain coffee experience by tweaking pour-over. Let me suggest a different approach. Pour-over has certain characteristics and benefits, but they're the opposite of your goal, and you'll be fighting its characteristics. The coffee experience you describe is what French Press produces naturally. You might want to explore that as a better starting point.

@Dolly - thank you, that is great advice.

A less uniform grind gives less even extraction, for better or worse. I think that's all you can predict from principles with any confidence. Reviews of grinders are the most reliable thing. The rest is all voodoo science, affirming and surprising in equal measure.

I think you're looking for a reason to keep your trusty ol' Skerton coffee mill ;) Honestly, why not stick with it if you're happy with it. I used a Skerton for a while though, and I can assure you it's tedious to operate, compared to almost anything else.
